# My image slideshow code won't work

Tags: javascript, image, slideshow

I'm trying to create an image cycle (or slideshow, as I've heard it called), in Javascript and HTML. I programmed this code bit, but it doesn't seem to work. What is stopping it from working? Someone asked to add the HTML. I also added the equal sign to the imageset, because that didn't fix the problem.

```html
<img src = '' id = 'HeaderPhotoImage'></img>

<button id = 'Change' onclick = ChangeImage()>Change</button>
```

```js
function ChangeImage() {

    var ImageOne = new Image();
    ImageOne.src = 'http://images.visitcanberra.com.au/images/canberra_hero_image.jpg';
    var ImageTwo = new Image();
    ImageTwo.src ='http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b6/Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png';
    var ImageThree = new Image();
    ImageThree.src = 'http://imageswiki.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/images-ImageVaultHandler.jpg';
    var ImageFour = new Image();
    ImageFour.src = 'http://www.wonderplugin.com/wp-content/plugins/wonderplugin-lightbox/images/demo-image2.jpg';
    var ImageSet=[ImageOne.src, ImageTwo.src, ImageThree.src, ImageFour.src];
    var CallImage = document.getElementById('HeaderPhotoImage').innerHTML;
    CallImage.src = ImageSet[0];
}
```

Comment: `var ImageSet = [ImageOne.src, ImageTwo.src, ImageThree.src, ImageFour.src];` You missed the `=` sign. Please share the HTML also

Comment: You've got syntax errors in your `ImageSet` array

Comment: did you use double quotation marks ? onclick="ChangeImage()"?